The Security review module says "Untrusted users are allowed to input dangerous HTML tags" when webforms are used
I get the warning in the title of this post from the security review module. By clicking
on "details" an explanation is provided about the possibility of using dangerous tags (the img tag in this case) by untrusted users. The message ends with the following:

The following formats are usable by untrusted roles and do not filter
or escape allowed HTML tags.
Webform (Default) - DO NOT EDIT

I've tried to correct the problem and to remove the problematic tag from the Webform (Default) text format by using the usual configuration tool for text formats: /admin/config/content/formats. But the problematic text format is not available in the list of text formats. Next, by doing some research, I've found that the Webform (Default) text format is hidden.
How can I correct the problem? How can I configure a hidden text format?
Here are the version of the software that I use:

drupal/core-recommended       10.2.2
drupal/webform 6.2.2
drupal/security_review        3.0.1

Thank you

Please add the versions of Drupal core, Webform module, and Security Review module that you are using.  This is the kind of issue that someone may try to reproduce, and the version info is essential to reproduction.

This is probably a false positive.
